# store the xml auto result of a sp in an xml variable

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a sp something like this

```
create proc disp
as
begin
select * from emp for xml auto
end
```

Now I want to store the result of the statement

```
exec disp
```

in an xml variable.

I tried something like

```
Declare @xmlvar XML
set @xmlvar = exec disp
```

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table variable to capture the output of the SP and then get the XML from the table.

```
declare @T table (xmlCol xml)
declare @xml xml

insert into @T
exec disp

select @xml = xmlCol
from @T
```

To get this to work you need to add [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190025.aspx) to the query in the SP.
Something like this...

```
create proc disp
as
begin
  select * from emp for xml auto, type
end
```

Comment: For some reasons I can't change the sp. Is there a way to do without that.

Comment: @Nadeem – Not that I know of.